# Searching for the amount of capital words in a text file Python

Tags: python, string, file, search, capitalization

I need help sorting through a text file

I have tried multiple variations of a for loop. I have also tried to strip all spaces and count the letters individually in the file. I have also tried multiple variations of the strip function and different if statements

```
for character in file:
    if character.isupper():
        capital += 1
        file.readline().rstrip()
        break

print(capital)
```

I expect the program to read each word or letter in the document and return the total amount of capitalized words contained within.

Comment: When you do `for character in file:` you are actually iterating **over the lines**, not **characters**.

Comment: How do I iterate over the characters in the lines?

Comment: You could use another loop to iterate over the characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say we have an example file `doc.txt` with this content:

> This is a test file for identifying Capital Words.
>   I created this as an Example because the question's requirements could vary.
>   For instance, should acronyms like SQL count as capital words?
>   If no: this should result in eight capital words.
>   If yes: this should result in nine.

If you wanted to count the capital (aka title case) words, but exclude all-caps words like acronyms, you could do something like this:

```
def count_capital_words(filename):                                               
    count = 0                                                                    
    with open(filename, 'r') as fp:                                              
        for line in fp:                                                          
            for word in line.split():                                            
                if word.istitle():                                               
                    print(word)                                                  
                    count += 1                                                   
    return count


print(count_capital_words('doc.txt'))  # 8
```

If all-caps words should be counted, you could modify the function to only check the first letter of a word. Note that the `filter(None, ...)` function will ensure `word` is never an empty string, avoiding the `IndexError` that would be thrown in those cases:

```
def count_capital_words(filename):                                               
    count = 0                                                                    
    with open(filename, 'r') as fp:                                              
        for line in fp:                                                          
            for word in filter(None, line.split()):                              
                if word[0].isupper():                                            
                    count += 1                                                   
    return count


print(count_capital_words('doc.txt'))  # 9
```

If you have more complicated requirements, you can get an iterable of words like this:

```
from itertools import chain                                                      


def get_words(filename):                                                         
    with open(filename, 'r') as fp:                                              
        words = chain.from_iterable(line.split() for line in fp)                 
        yield from words
```

Answer (score 1):

If the objective is to count words which start with capital letters then I would use fact that boolean value is subtype of integer:

```
with open('my_textfile.txt', 'r') as text:
    print(sum(word.istitle() for row in text for word in row))
```

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

1. Make sure you are iterating over characters and not words or sentences. Put some print statements to check.
2. Remove the break statement in your if block. This is immediately exiting your for loop and will lead to you only ever counting 1.

```
for sentence in file:
    for char in sentence:
        if char.isupper():
            capital += 1

print(capital)
```

Comment: Shouldn't iteration be over words? OP defined objective as: 'to find the amount of capital words'. For example O'Reilly is one capital word which has two uppercase letters. It seems that str.istitle() is more suitable for achieving objective.

Comment: Subtle but very important point. I agree. Iterate over words and use .istitle() would be the most appropriate approach.